# Accountsservice hangs with installation

Tags: 16.04

I made my usual updates for ubuntu 16.04 LTS and at the end it was installing accountsservice, but there it hangs with the message "accountsservice (0.6.40-2ubuntu11.6) install". I tried already to delete the "lock file" and did  "sudo dpkg --configure -a", but then it always starts the installation of the accountsservice again and hangs again. What can I do to get the rid of it?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like following command fixes the issue

```
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon
```